# Remove double spaces without removing bullet levels

Tags: vba

Whenever I run the code in the powerpoint it remove all the bullets from the textranges, textframes but i want to keep all bullets as it is if anybody know please advise

```
Sub removeSpaces()
Dim shpText As String

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            shpText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Get the shape's text
            Do While InStr(shpText, "  ") > 0
                shpText = Trim(Replace(shpText, "  ", " "))
            Loop
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shpText 'Put the new text in the shape

        Else
            shpText = vbNullString
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Unclear. Please edit question and clarify: what is this code supposed to do, and what does it do ?

Comment: Can't reproduce that behavior: doesn't remove bullets from mt test slide...

Answer (score 0):

Remove trim and try.

```
Do While InStr(shpText, "  ") > 0
   shpText = Replace(shpText, "  ", " ")
Loop
```